# Need Help in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table looks like this:

```
    ITEMCODE   CP_ID   Wloc   Color   Status   STOCK_DATE
---------------------------------------------------------
1   259        1       148    71      I        10/30/2014
2   259        1       148    71      I        10/30/2014
3   259        1       148    71      B        10/30/2014
4   259        1       148    71      I        10/30/2014
5   259        1       148    71      D        10/30/2014
6   259        1       148    71      D        10/29/2014
7   259        1       148    71      B        10/29/2014
8   259        1       148    71      I        10/29/2014
9   259        1       148    71      I        10/29/2014
```

The status codes are

```
I Inward
B Blocked
D Dispatched
```

I'm looking for a stock report like

```
ITEM_CODE   Opening_Stock   Closing_Stock   Outward_STOCK   Blocked_Stock   Inward_Stock    Stock_Date
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
259         0               1               1               1               2               10/29/2014
259         1               3               1               1               3               10/30/2014
```

Blocked is available and not yet dispatched.

Trying Some thing like got for current date  looking for all dates..

```
Select  Distinct
        ITEMCODE    as ITEM_CODE,
        '0'         as Opening_Stock,
        (
            Select  count(status)
            From    sysdba.stock
            Where   status = 'I'
            And     stock_date = date
            Group By Itemcode
        ) as INWARD_STOCK,
        (
            Select  count(status)
            From    sysdba.stock
            Where   status = 'D'
            And     stock_date = date
            Group By Itemcode
        ) as OUTWARD_STOCK,
        (
            Select  count(status)
            From    sysdba.stock
            Where   status = 'B'
            And     stock_date = date
            Group By Itemcode
        ) as BLOCKED_STOCK,
        (Opening_stock + INWARD_STOCK - OUTWARD_STOCK)  as Closing_Stock,
        Stock_date
From    sysdba.stock
Where   stock_date = date
Group By ITEMCODE, STOCK_DATE
```

How do I go about building this report?

All help is appreciated!

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: `Any help appreciated` is not a question.

Comment: Explain why you get the sample result, and edit the original table so that it can be read. There are more fields than headings

Comment: You need to make your post legible. It is nearly impossible in a forum to post data like that. sqlfiddle.com is a good place to start.

Comment: Marc,Rick Tried Muliple Option Like SubQuery,Rank etc nothing working thus Need some help or a Hint.

Comment: With no explanation of what the output actually means anybody is just guessing. There are some business rules involved here which are clear in your head but are not clear to anybody else because they are not posted. This is probably a pretty simple query but with no details it is shooting in the dark.

Comment: I would break it up into smaller tasks.  The first task is how to establish opening stock, I think.  Could it be `select sum(inward_stock - outward_stock) where stock_date < :Some Date group by item_code` ???

Comment: `select distinct ITEMCODE as ITEM_CODE,
'0' as Opening_Stock,
(select count(status) from sysdba.stock where status='I'  and ITEMCODE=ITEM_CODE group by Itemcode,stock_date) as INWARD_STOCK,
(select count(status) from sysdba.stock where status='D' group by Itemcode,stock_date) as OUTWARD_STOCK.
(select count(status) from sysdba.stock where status='B' group by Itemcode,stock_date) as BLOCKED_STOCK.
(Opening_stock+INWARD_STOCK-OUTWARD_STOCK) as Closing_Stock
Stock_date
from sysdba.stock  group by ITEMCODE,STOCK_DATE`

Comment: Sub Queries are generating Multiple Records... :-( but we need both the records. trying to Ranking them.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Need one more help.. In my trigger below Group By is not acceptable.. Any other Hint to modify it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer but perhaps someone else will run with this.

```
SELECT
    ITEMCODE  as ITEM_CODE,
    0 AS Opening_Stock,
    SUM(CASE status 
            WHEN 'D' THEN -1 
            WHEN 'I' THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END) AS Closing_Stock,
    SUM(CASE [status] WHEN 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OUTWARD_STOCK,
    SUM(CASE [status] WHEN 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BLOCKED_STOCK,
    SUM(CASE [status] WHEN 'I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS INWARD_STOCK,
    Stock_date
FROM    dbo.Table_1 a
--WHERE   stock_date = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
GROUP BY ITEMCODE, STOCK_DATE
```

My guess is that @Machha wants yesterday's `Closing_Stock` to be today's `Opening_Stock`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [DBO].[Stock_close] ON [DBO].[ITEM_INWARD] after
UPDATE,
INSERT AS IF EXISTS
   (
          SELECT Count(*)
          FROM   stock_close_rpt xx,
                 inserted yy
          WHERE  Cast(xx.stock_date AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE)
          AND    xx.item_code=yy.item_code
   )
   BEGIN
UPDATE stock_close_rpt
SET      item_code=a.item_code ,
     opening_stock=
     (
            SELECT closing_stock =
                   CASE
                          WHEN
                                 (
                                        SELECT closing_stock
                                        FROM   stock_close_rpt
                                        WHERE  Cast(stock_date AS DATE) =
                                               (
                                                      SELECT Max(Cast(stock_date AS DATE))
                                                      FROM   stock_close_rpt c,
                                                             inserted d
                                                      WHERE  c.item_code=d.item_code)) IS NOT       NULL THEN closing_stock
                          ELSE '0'
                   END
            FROM   stock_close_rpt ),
     inward_stock=
     (
            SELECT status =
                   CASE
                          WHEN
                                 (
                                          SELECT   Count(ab.status)
                                          FROM     item_inward ab,
                                                   inserted cd
                                          WHERE    ab.status = 'I'
                                          AND      Cast(ab.dt_added AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE )
                                          AND      ab.item_code=cd.item_code
                                          AND      ab.colour_id=cd.colour_id
                                          GROUP BY ab.item_code,
                                                   ab.colour_id) IS NOT NULL THEN Count(status)
                          ELSE '0'
                   END
            FROM   item_inward
            WHERE  status = 'I'
            AND    Cast(dt_added AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE )),
     outward_stock=
     (
            SELECT status =
                   CASE
                          WHEN
                                 (
                                          SELECT   Count(ab.status)
                                          FROM     item_inward ab,
                                                   inserted cd
                                          WHERE    ab.status = 'D'
                                          AND      Cast(ab.dt_added AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE )
                                          AND      ab.item_code=cd.item_code
                                          AND      ab.colour_id=cd.colour_id
                                          GROUP BY ab.item_code,
                                                   ab.colour_id ) IS NOT NULL THEN Count(status)
                          ELSE '0'
                   END
            FROM   item_inward
            WHERE  status = 'D'
            AND    Cast(dt_added AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE ) ),
     blocked_stock=
     (
            SELECT status =
                   CASE
                          WHEN
                                 (
                                          SELECT   Count(ab.status)
                                          FROM     item_inward ab,
                                                   inserted cd
                                          WHERE    ab.status = 'B'
                                          AND      Cast(ab.dt_added AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE )
                                          AND      ab.item_code=cd.item_code
                                          AND      ab.colour_id=cd.colour_id
                                          GROUP BY ab.item_code,
                                                   ab.colour_id ) IS NOT NULL THEN Count(status)
                          ELSE '0'
                   END
            FROM   item_inward
            WHERE  status = 'B'
            AND    Cast(dt_added AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE )) ,
     closing_stock=(
     (
            SELECT closing_stock =
                   CASE
                          WHEN
                                 (
                                        SELECT closing_stock
                                        FROM   stock_close_rpt
                                        WHERE  Cast(stock_date AS DATE) =
                                               (
                                                      SELECT Max(Cast(stock_date AS DATE))
                                                      FROM   stock_close_rpt c,
                                                             inserted d
                                                      WHERE  c.item_code=d.item_code)) IS NOT NULL THEN closing_stock
                          ELSE '0'
                   END
            FROM   stock_close_rpt )+(
     (
            SELECT status =
                   CASE
                          WHEN
                                 (
                                          SELECT   Count(ab.status)
                                          FROM     item_inward ab,
                                                   inserted cd
                                          WHERE    ab.status = 'I'
                                          AND      Cast(ab.dt_added AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE )
                                          AND      ab.item_code=cd.item_code
                                          AND      ab.colour_id=cd.colour_id
                                          GROUP BY ab.item_code,
                                                   ab.colour_id ) IS NOT NULL THEN Count(status)
                          ELSE '0'
                   END
            FROM   item_inward
            WHERE  status = 'I'
            AND    Cast(dt_added AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE )) -
     (
            SELECT status =
                   CASE
                          WHEN
                                 (
                                          SELECT   Count(ab.status)
                                          FROM     item_inward ab,
                                                   inserted cd
                                          WHERE    ab.status = 'D'
                                          AND      Cast(ab.dt_added AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE )
                                          AND      ab.item_code=cd.item_code
                                          AND      ab.colour_id=cd.colour_id
                                          GROUP BY ab.item_code,
                                                   ab.colour_id ) IS NOT NULL THEN Count(status)
                          ELSE '0'
                   END
            FROM   item_inward
            WHERE  status = 'D'
            AND    Cast(dt_added AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE ) ))),
     colour_id= a.colour_id,
     stock_date=a.dt_added,
     cp_id=a.cp_id
FROM     dbo.item_inward a,
     inserted b
WHERE    a.item_code=b.item_code
AND      Cast(a.dt_added AS DATE)=Cast(b.dt_added AS DATE)
group BY a.dt_added,
     a.item_code,
     a.colour_id,
     a.cp_id ;

END
ELSE
BEGIN
INSERT INTO stock_close_rpt
SELECT   a.item_code ,
         (
                SELECT closing_stock =
                       CASE
                              WHEN
                                     (
                                            SELECT closing_stock
                                            FROM   stock_close_rpt
                                            WHERE  Cast(stock_date AS DATE) =
                                                   (
                                                          SELECT Max(Cast(stock_date AS DATE))
                                                          FROM   stock_close_rpt c,
                                                                 inserted d
                                                          WHERE  c.item_code=d.item_code)) IS NOT NULL THEN closing_stock
                              ELSE '0'
                                            END
                FROM   stock_close_rpt ) AS opening_stock,
         (
                SELECT status =
                       CASE
                              WHEN
                                     (
                                              SELECT   Count(ab.status)
                                              FROM     item_inward ab,
                                                       inserted cd
                                              WHERE    ab.status = 'I'
                                              AND      Cast(ab.dt_added AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE )
                                              AND      ab.item_code=cd.item_code
                                              AND      ab.colour_id=cd.colour_id
                                              GROUP BY ab.item_code,
                                                       ab.colour_id ) IS NOT NULL THEN Count(status)
                              ELSE '0'
                       END
                FROM   item_inward
                WHERE  status = 'I'
                AND    Cast(dt_added AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE )) AS inward_stock,
         (
                SELECT status =
                       CASE
                              WHEN
                                     (
                                              SELECT   Count(ab.status)
                                              FROM     item_inward ab,
                                                       inserted cd
                                              WHERE    ab.status = 'D'
                                              AND      Cast(ab.dt_added AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE )
                                              AND      ab.item_code=cd.item_code
                                              AND      ab.colour_id=cd.colour_id
                                              GROUP BY ab.item_code,
                                                       ab.colour_id ) IS NOT NULL THEN Count(status)
                              ELSE '0'
                       END
                FROM   item_inward
                WHERE  status = 'D'
                AND    Cast(dt_added AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE ) ) AS outward_stock,
         (
                SELECT status =
                       CASE
                              WHEN
                                     (
                                              SELECT   Count(ab.status)
                                              FROM     item_inward ab,
                                                       inserted cd
                                              WHERE    ab.status = 'B'
                                              AND      Cast(ab.dt_added AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE )
                                              AND      ab.item_code=cd.item_code
                                              AND      ab.colour_id=cd.colour_id
                                              GROUP BY ab.item_code,
                                                       ab.colour_id ) IS NOT NULL THEN Count(status)
                              ELSE '0'
                       END
                FROM   item_inward
                WHERE  status = 'B'
                AND    Cast(dt_added AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE )) AS blocked_stock,
         (
         (
                SELECT closing_stock =
                       CASE
                              WHEN
                                     (
                                            SELECT closing_stock
                                            FROM   stock_close_rpt
                                            WHERE  Cast(stock_date AS DATE) =
                                                   (
                                                          SELECT Max(Cast(stock_date AS DATE))
                                                          FROM   stock_close_rpt c,
                                                                 inserted d
                                                          WHERE  c.item_code=d.item_code)) IS NOT NULL THEN closing_stock
                              ELSE '0'
                       END
                FROM   stock_close_rpt )+(
         (
                SELECT status =
                       CASE
                              WHEN
                                     (
                                              SELECT   Count(ab.status)
                                              FROM     item_inward ab,
                                                       inserted cd
                                              WHERE    ab.status = 'I'
                                              AND      Cast(ab.dt_added AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE )
                                              AND      ab.item_code=cd.item_code
                                              AND      ab.colour_id=cd.colour_id
                                              GROUP BY ab.item_code,
                                                       ab.colour_id ) IS NOT NULL THEN Count(status)
                              ELSE '0'
                       END
                FROM   item_inward
                WHERE  status = 'I'
                AND    Cast(dt_added AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE )) -
         (
                SELECT status =
                       CASE
                              WHEN
                                     (
                                              SELECT   Count(ab.status)
                                              FROM     item_inward ab,
                                                       inserted cd
                                              WHERE    ab.status = 'D'
                                              AND      Cast(ab.dt_added AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE )
                                              AND      ab.item_code=cd.item_code
                                              AND      ab.colour_id=cd.colour_id
                                              GROUP BY ab.item_code,
                                                       ab.colour_id ) IS NOT NULL THEN Count(status)
                              ELSE '0'
                       END
                FROM   item_inward
                WHERE  status = 'D'
                AND    Cast(dt_added AS DATE) = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE ) ))) AS closing_stock,
         a.colour_id,
         a.cp_id,
         a.dt_added
FROM     dbo.item_inward a,
         inserted b
WHERE    a.item_code=b.item_code
AND      Cast(a.dt_added AS DATE)=Cast(b.dt_added AS DATE)
GROUP BY a.dt_added,
         a.item_code,
         a.colour_id,
         a.cp_id;

 END
```